# How to fix syntax error in MySQL at SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Getting a syntax error starting with the SELECT statement on line 8. Not sure why. Any ideas? See comment in code where error starts.

I thought it could have something to do with referring to Login l a second time, but when I tried changing it to Login o I still got the same error.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE setAttendance(IN _sectionid integer, IN _studentid integer, IN _logindate datetime, IN _result integer)

BEGIN

UPDATE Login l
INNER JOIN Roll r ON l.rollid = r.tid
SET result = _result
WHERE
r.sectionid = _sectionid AND r.studentid = _studentid 
AND DATE(logindate) = DATE(_logindate);

//error starts here and ends on line after it
SELECT tid FROM Login l
INNER JOIN Roll r ON l.rollid = r.tid
WHERE
r.sectionid = _sectionid AND r.studentid = _studentid 
AND DATE(logindate) = DATE(_logindate);
```

I just want to run this without syntax errors

Comment: This problem is usually due to missing `DELIMITER` statements.

Comment: Sorry I didn't show the DELIMETER statements here bc I thought it was unnecessary, but I do have them in my actual code

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code (other than the use of the incorrect comment character to indicate where the error is) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6af8a2dff1b517dc6f560777a2fee581

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually due to missing `DELIMITER`, but I also recommend simplifying the date arithmetic so it is more index friendly and qualifying *all* column names:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE setAttendance (
    IN _sectionid integer,
    IN _studentid integer,
    IN _logindate datetime,
    IN _result integer
)
BEGIN

    UPDATE Login l INNER JOIN
           Roll r
           ON l.rollid = r.tid
        SET result = _result
    WHERE r.sectionid = _sectionid AND 
          r.studentid = _studentid AND
          ?.logindate >= DATE(_logindate) AND   -- the ? is for the table alias
          ?.logindate < DATE(_logindate) + INTERVAL 1 DAY;


    //error starts here and ends on line after it

    SELECT r.tid    -- table alias
    FROM Login l INNER JOIN 
         Roll r
         ON l.rollid = r.tid
    WHERE r.sectionid = _sectionid AND
          r.studentid = _studentid AND
          ?.logindate >= DATE(_logindate) AND   -- the ? is for the table alias
          ?.logindate < DATE(_logindate) + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
END; $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Note that the question marks are for you to include the appropriate table alias.  Qualify *all* column names.